# Error using CrystaX within Buildozer building an APK

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

Currently using the Kivy/Buildozer VM in order to convert a Python Script into an APK, however everytime I use "buildozer android debug" I end up with this error;

```
[INFO]:    # Prebuilding recipes
[INFO]:    Prebuilding hostpython3crystax for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    hostpython3crystax has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding sdl2_image for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    sdl2_image has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Applying patches for sdl2_image[armeabi-v7a]
[INFO]:    sdl2_image already patched, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding sdl2_mixer for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    sdl2_mixer has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Applying patches for sdl2_mixer[armeabi-v7a]
[INFO]:    sdl2_mixer already patched, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding sdl2_ttf for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    sdl2_ttf has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding python3crystax for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    python3crystax has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[ERROR]:   The python3crystax recipe can only be built when using the CrystaX NDK. Exiting.
```

I have downloaded and extracted the CrystaX NDK and have written its path and version in my buildozer.spec file as well;

```
# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 10.3.2

# (list) Application requirements
requirements = python3crystax,kivy

# (str) Point to the directory where you extracted the crystax-ndk:
#android.ndk_path = ~/kivy/Downloads/crystax-ndk-10.3.2/
```

Any help to correct this error would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry about that, have edited it and hopefully it's more clear now. Thanks.

Comment: Edit `buildozer.spec` and remove `#` (comment) for `android.ndk = 10.3.2` and `android.ndk_path = ~/kivy/Downloads/crystax-ndk-10.3.2/`